# If $f=F'$ and $|f|$ is Riemann integrable, how to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R $. Suppose that there exists $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ and that $|f|$ is Riemann integrable.

How to show $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: I made some small edits - hope I did the question justice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f$ is continuous everywhere $|f|$ is.  This is not true in general for real valued functions, but it is true for derivatives.

Suppose that $|f|$ is continuous at $c$.  So $\lim\limits_{x\to c}|f(x)|=|f(c)|$.  If $f(c)=0$, then it follows that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=0$.  Suppose that $f(c)\neq 0$, and suppose, to reach a contradiction, that $f$ is not continuous at $c$.  Because $|f|$ is continuous at $c$, this implies that $f$ takes on both positive and negative values in every neighborhood of $c$.  Let $\delta>0$ be such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $||f(x)|-|f(c)||<|f(c)|$.  Then $|x-c|<\delta$ implies that $f(x)\neq 0$.  Since $f$ takes on both positive and negative values on $\{x:|x-c|<\delta\}$, this implies that $f$ does not have the intermediate value property.  This violates [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29). It was the assumption that $f$ is not continuous at $c$ that led to this contradiction, so $f$ is in fact continuous at $c$.

A bounded function on $[a,b]$ is [Riemann integrable if and only if the set of points where it is discontinuous has measure zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).  This holds for $|f|$, hence also for $f$.

Comment: Nice answer Jonas. Could you also comment about the unbounded case ? This is just a curiosity since more likely the question is about bounded $f$.

Comment: @Leandro: Strictly speaking $|f|$ must be bounded in order to be Riemann integrable, so $f$ must be bounded given the problem as stated.  If $|f|$ is unbounded, and the integrability is meant in some improper sense, then the same reasoning applies on subintervals where $f$ is bounded, and convergence of the improper Riemann integral of $|f|$ implies convergence of the improper Rieman integral of $f$.  E.g., if $\lim_{y\to b}\int_a^y|f(x)|dx$ exists, and $(x_n)\nearrow b$, then you can show that $(\int_a^{x_n}f(x)dx)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then argue that $\lim_{y\to b}\int_a^yf(x)dx$ exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jonas.

Comment: @[commenter]: "Did you mean the first sentence to only apply in the case when there exists $F$ such that $F'=f$?"  Yes, and that is what I intended the second sentence to convey. "Since you didn't use that fact...."  Notice that later Darboux's theorem is invoked; derivatives have the intermediate value property.  [This was a reply to comments that were deleted seconds before I posted.  I guess that the commenter realized the answer their own concerns, but I'll leave this reply for now in case it helps.  Perhaps I'll delete it sometime.]