# Prove that if $|g'(x)|\leq M|x-x_0|^n$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|g(x)|\leq \frac{M|x-x_0|^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

I really don't know how to proceed. 
There is similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487299/show-that-if-gx-leq-mx-an-for-x-a-delta-then-gx-ga-leq?noredirect=1&lq=1) but in that case, they prove that $|g(x)-g(a)|\leq \frac{M|x-x_0|^{n+1}}{n+1}$ instead of just $|g(x)|$ so I got really confused.

I hope that yoy could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is not correct. Take $g(x)=x^2+7, x_0=0$ and $n=1$.