# Is $F$ Riemann integrable, then $F'$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I know **Newton-Leibnetz theorem**: 
if $f \in \mathcal{R}[a ,b]$($f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a ,b]$), and if exists differentiable function $F$ satisfy $F'=f$ on $[a, b]$, then
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a).$$
And I wonder if $F$ is Riemann integrable, whether or not $F'=f$ is Riemann integrable? I can't see it directly from Newton-Leibnetz theorem since it firstly acquires $f$ to be Riemann integrable, which is what I want to prove.

I referred [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93370/if-f-f-and-f-is-riemann-integrable-how-to-show-that-f-is-riemann-integ), but it was talking about $|f|$ is integrable.

Edit: if $F'$ is not, how to make it is Riemann integrable? Such as making $F$ be differentiable over $[a, b]$?

Comment: $F$ being Riemann integrable doesn't imply $F$ is differentiable at any point. Indeed there are continuous, nowhere differentiable functions, and every continuous function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: I have editted my question, but I guess that letting $F$ be differentiable over $[a, b]$ is still not enough. Am I right? @Ian

Comment: You are correct. There are functions which are differentiable with bounded derivative yet the derivative is not Riemann integrable. E.g. [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).